# laravel route filter to check user roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am building a restful api in laravel 4 where there are users with different types of permission.  I want to restrict access to different routes depending on the user role (which is saved in the user table in db)

How would I do that?  Here is what I have so far (it's not working so far).

filters.php

```
//allows backend api access depending on the user's role once they are logged in
Route::filter('role', function()
{ 
return Auth::user()->role;
});
```

routes.php

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'role'), function($role) {
 if($role==1){
        Route::get('customer/retrieve/{id}', 'CustomerController@retrieve_single');
        Route::post('customer/create', 'CustomerController@create');
        Route::put('customer/update/{id}', 'CustomerController@update');
 }

    });
```

Is it possible that I'm writing the syntax wrong for a "group filter"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('role', function()
{ 
  if ( Auth::user()->role !==1) {
     // do something
     return Redirect::to('/'); 
   }
});
```

**routes.php**

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'role'), function() {
        Route::get('customer/retrieve/{id}', 'CustomerController@retrieve_single');
        Route::post('customer/create', 'CustomerController@create');
        Route::put('customer/update/{id}', 'CustomerController@update');


});
```

Comment: Exactly...It should works.... But if you need do it for multiple roles we need to change filter route like `Route::filter('role', function()
{ 
  $roles = ['2','3','4'];
  if (!in_array(Auth::user()->role, $roles)) {
     return Redirect:to('/'); 
   }
}); `

Answer (score 5):

There are different ways you could implement this, for starts Route filters accept arguments:

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value)
{
  //
});

Route::get('someurl', array('before' => 'role:admin', function()
{
  //
}));
```

The above will inject admin in your Route::filter, accessible through the $value parameter.
If you need more complicated filtering you can always use a custom route filter class (check Filter Classes):
http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

You can also filter within your controller, which provides a better approach when you need to filter based on specific controllers and methods:
http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters

Finally you can use something like Sentry2, which provides a complete RBAC solution to use within your project:
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry

Answer (score 0):

From laravel 5.1.11 you can use the AuthServiceProvider: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization