# Laravel 4.2- how to allow access only for logged/authorized user

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have created login form and using Auth method for authorizing user with email and password. Login is done be doLogin function in HomeControler

```
public function doLogin()
    {

        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
        );


        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
                ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
        } else {


            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );


            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            $id = Auth::id();

            return Redirect::to('panel');

            } else {        


                return Redirect::to('login');

            }

        }
    }
```

In my routes.php file I have created route to get user by id and before that check if user is logged in.

```
Route::get('panel/{id}', array('before' => 'auth', function($id)
{   
    $user=User::find($id);
    dd($user);

}));
```

I have faced 2 problems so far:

1. – How I can create route with get parameters in doLogin function, so that it redirects user in panel/id/ address?
   return Redirect::to('panel')->with('id', $id);  is not working!
2. And second problem is that panel/{id} route is checking if user is logged in with 'before' => 'auth', but if I logged in with User id 1 and then opened address panel/2/ it opens the current route. How I can make laravel to check that user id that is logged in mit opens the current route. How I can make laravel to check that user id that is logged in matches the user ID that is requested in route?atches the user ID that is requested in route?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794225/laravel-route-filter-to-check-user-roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extends all of controllers you want to authorize from BaseController.

BaseController could be

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth');
  }
}
```

then forget about it, it works fine.