# How to make a route filters base on user type in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

> **Goal**: I want to make route filter in Laravel 4 using `Route::group` and `Route::filter`

---

> **Description**

I have 2 types of user :

1. Internal
2. Distributor

For, `Internal`, I have 2 groups:

- admin
- regular

For `Distributor`, I have 4 groups:

- gold
- silver
- bronze
- oem

> **Eligible Route**

OEM Distributor are eligible for only 5 routes.

```
Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));
Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');
```

Regular Distributor are eligible for 8 routes.

```
Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));
Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');
Route::get('marketing_materials','MarketingMaterialController@index');
Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path','MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path','MarketingMaterialController@media_download');
```

> **Code**

- [filters.php](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/filters.php)
- [routes.php](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/routes.php).

> **Questions**

- Can someone please help me or at least direct me to the **right direction** ?

Comment: You know to determine the user's group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: It's not possibble to declare a route that **results in the same URL** twice. Whether it's in a group or not. (Well if you have a group with `prefix` it's possible because a prefix changes to URL of the route)

You have to solve this problem by **intelligent filtering**

This is the simplest solution I've come up with:

```
Route::filter('distributor', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type == "Distributor"){
        return true;
    }
    if (Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    }
    return View::make('errors.404_auth');
});

Route::filter('distributor.regular', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type == "Distributor"){
        if($user->distributor()->type != 'OEM'){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    }
    return View::make('errors.404_auth');
});
```

The `distributor` filter checks just if the user is of type `Distributor`. The second filter, `distributor.regular`, checks if the distributor is not an OEM. (If you're wondering, the dot in `distributor.regular` has no special function or deeper meaning. I just like to write it like that)

```
Route::group(['before' => 'distributor'], function(){
    Route::get('distributors/{id}', array('before' =>'profile', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@show'));
    Route::get('distributors/{id}/edit', 'DistributorController@edit');
    Route::put('distributors/{id}/update', array('as'=>'distributors.update', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@update'));
    Route::get('catalog_downloads','CatalogDownloadController@index');
    Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download','CatalogDownloadController@file_download');

    Route::group(['before' => 'distributor.regular'], function(){
        Route::get('catalog_downloads', 'CatalogDownloadController@index');
        Route::get('catalog_downloads/{id}/download', 'CatalogDownloadController@file_download');
        Route::get('marketing_materials', 'MarketingMaterialController@index');
        Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/thumb_path', 'MarketingMaterialController@thumb_download');
        Route::get('marketing_materials/{id}/download/media_path', 'MarketingMaterialController@media_download');
    });
});
```

This should already work with the use-cases you posted. However we can make the filters more flexible and also reduce redundant code.

```
function makeError404(){
    if (Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 404);
    }
    return View::make('errors.404_auth');
}

Route::filter('distributor', function(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type == "Distributor"){
        return true;
    }
    return makeError404();
});

Route::filter('distributor.group', function($route, $request, $value){
    $groups = explode(';', $value);
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->type == "Distributor"){
        if(in_array($user->distributor()->type, $groups)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return makeError404();
});
```

Now we can dynamically specify in which group the user has to be...

```
Route::group(['before' => 'distributor'], function(){
    // distributor routes

    Route::group(['before' => 'distributor.group:gold;silver;bronze'], function(){
        // regular routes
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow a path like this

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('employee', array('only' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which file should I try with block of code in ? `filters.php` ? Can you please kindly quickly explain this code ? If you don't mind.

Comment: Of course. filter.php file will have a filter called employee. This filter will determine the user's role. Controller will do it automatically. A similar example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794225/laravel-route-filter-to-check-user-roles You can also benefit from the documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters and

Comment: After tweaking my filters.php , do I need to do anything specific inside my routes.php ?

Comment: Not the routes. Controller also as above $ this-> beforeFilter is ('employee', array ('only' => 'index')); You must run the filter.

Comment: I don't get it. I'm sorry. Can you fix your answer and add more details on which code going into what file ? I feel so confuse a bit right now. If your answer is work. I will reward u 50+ Rep. Just add more details, please. So far, I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Where ? I didn't see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65976/discussion-between-olgundutkan-and-evoque2015).