# How to add multiple roles to a route group laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to add multiple roles to a route group in my `web` file in Laravel.
I would like protect certain routes based on the users Role like the admin section.

Some Routes need multiple roles for access.

**Example Roles:**

- SuperAdmin
- Admin
- Moderator
- etc..

This works and I can go to the admin panel if loged in and have ***One Role*** only in the route group.

```
Route::middleware(['auth','role:SuperAdmin'])->group(function () {
Secret routes..
});
```

> This does not work if I try and add more roles to to the route group
> like this: `Route::middleware(['auth','role:SuperAdmin|Admin|Moderator'])->group(function () {`

Note the `'role:SuperAdmin|Admin|Moderator'`

---

**This is the RoleMiddleware file:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission = null)
    {
        if (!$request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        if ($permission !== null && !$request->user()->can($permission)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

---

The `User Class` has a trait called `use:HasPermissionTrait`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasPermissionsTrait, Billable;
```

**In that HasPermissionsTrait I have the following:**
I have permission setup fine, just focusing on the Roles in this file. I moved the Role logic to the top.

```
use App\{Role, Permission};

trait HasPermissionsTrait
{
    public function hasRole(...$roles)
    {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if ($this->roles->contains('name', $role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');
    }
    
    ... // Permission logic start here...
}
```

---

**Worth Mentioning:**
The tables for roles are:

- users
- roles
- users_roles (I know the correct naming convention should be `roles_users`, but not relevant here)

> Just need to know how to get this working in the route group:
> `'role:SuperAdmin|Admin|Moderator'`

---

**Solution:**
RoleMiddleware file:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission = null)
    {
        $role = strtolower( $request->user()->hasRole($role));
        $allowed_roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
        
        if (!$request->user()->hasRole(in_array($role, $allowed_roles))) {
            abort(404);
        }

        if ($permission !== null && !$request->user()->can($permission)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Can do route group like this.
`Route::middleware(['auth','role:SuperAdmin|Admin'])->group(function () {`

Comment: see routes filters : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20794357/10573560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in my `CheckRole Middleware`

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    // I'm using the api guard
    $role = strtolower( request()->user()->type );
    $allowed_roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);

    if( in_array($role, $allowed_roles) ) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

And in my router file

```php
Route::group(["middleware" => "role:admin,worker"], function() {

});
```

---

This might not be the perfect solution, at least it works for me.

Comment: Wow this actually worked after a little adjusting. Thank you!

Comment: I added my solution to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
      //Routes available to super admin
      Route::middleware(['role:SuperAdmin'])->group(function () {
        //write route hear 
      });
        
      //Routes available to SuperAdmin, Admin and Moderator
      Route::middleware(['role:SuperAdmin|Admin|Moderator'])->group(function () {
        //write route hear 
      })
  });
```

try this way to define route group of routing. I already use this syntax and it's work.

define auth in parent middleware group and roles defined in the child middleware groupe.

Comment: This is something I'm going for. Tried your solution, but still returns the 404 from the `abort(404);`

Answer (score 0):

[`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the roles in your middleware and check against the available roles

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission = null)
{
    $roles = is_array($role)
        ? $role
        : explode('|', $role);

    if (!$request->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    if ($permission !== null && !$request->user()->can($permission)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Get error `Call to undefined method App\User::hasAnyRole()` because I don't have that method. What would the `hasAnyRoute` contain. Does it go in the Trait ?

Comment: @echo check with the hasRole method

Comment: Still getting the `abort(404)` Doning this in the route: `Route::middleware(['auth','role:SuperAdmin|Admin'])->group(function () {`

Comment: @echo Can you do a `dd($role)` in your middleware and post the response

Comment: dd = `"SuperAdmin|Admin"`

Comment: how is the roles defined in the user model, could you share that...since your table name for the relation is different

Comment: it's defined via the trait `HasPermissionsTrait` like this: `public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');
    }` You can see it in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216400/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-echo).

Comment: Actually just got it working. Posted my soultion in the question. Let me know your thoughts. Thank you for your help.